# I'm trying to make this code works to source the Most zero day options trading in Bloomberg terminal I have access any hehelp

Tags: python, bloomberg

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from xbbg import blp

def inspect_options_data(specific_day='2023-8-17'):
    try:
        # Fetch bulk options data for S&P 500 Index
        options_data = blp.bds(tickers='SPX Index', flds=['OPT_EXIRE_DT'== specific_day, 'OPT_CHAIN'])
        
        # Filter for call options with the specified expiration date
        call_options = options_data[options_data['security_description'].str.contains(f'{specific_day} C')].copy()
        
        # Filter for put options with the specified expiration date
        put_options = options_data[options_data['security_description'].str.contains(f'{specific_day} P')].copy()
        
        # Extract the strike price from the 'security_description' column
        call_options['strike'] = call_options['security_description'].str.extract(f'C(\d+) ').astype(float)
        call_options['type'] = 'Call'
        
        # Extract the strike price from the 'security_description' column
        put_options['strike'] = put_options['security_description'].str.extract(f'P(\d+) ').astype(float)
        put_options['type'] = 'Put'
        
        # Fetch volume data for each option and ensure it's a scalar value
        put_options['px_volume'] = put_options['security_description'].apply(lambda x: blp.bdp(tickers=x, flds=['PX_VOLUME']).iloc[0, 0])
        call_options['px_volume'] = call_options['security_description'].apply(lambda x: blp.bdp(tickers=x, flds=['PX_VOLUME']).iloc[0, 0])
        
        # Combine puts and calls data
        combined_data = pd.concat([put_options, call_options])
        
        # Sort by volume in descending order and select the top 10
        top_10_options = combined_data.sort_values(by='px_volume', ascending=False).head(10)
        
        # Visualization
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        plt.bar(top_10_options['security_description'], top_10_options['px_volume'], color=['red' if t == 'Put' else 'green' for t in top_10_options['type']])
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.xlabel('Option Description')
        plt.ylabel('Volume')
        plt.title(f'Top 10 Options for {specific_day}')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Inspect the options data
inspect_options_data()
```

But its only provide me the result for the regular expiration.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [mre].

Comment: Have you asked Bloomberg support?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use BQL for this.

```
import bql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

bq = bql.Service()

expire_date = '2023-09-20'

query = f"""
get(SECURITY_DES, STRIKE_PX, OPEN_INT, PX_VOLUME, DELTA, EXPIRE_DT)
for(filter(options('SPY US EQUITY'), GROUPRANK(PX_VOLUME(D), ORDER=DESC) <= 11 and EXPIRE_DT() == {expire_date}))
with(MODE=CACHED)
"""

data = bql.combined_df(bq.execute(query)).groupby('ID').last().sort_values(by='PX_VOLUME',ascending=False)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))
sb.barplot(data=data, x='SECURITY_DES',y='PX_VOLUME', hue="PUT_CALL", palette=['red','green'], dodge=False)
plt.title(f'Top 10 Options for {expire_date}')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Option Description')
plt.ylabel('Volume')
plt.show()
```

[image]